# Current time is differed by 6hrs 30min when storing into mongoDB database with Date as Datatype in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, datetime, time

I've took the Date as the datatype and inserted one record in mongoDB. It is inserted as 2020-04-23T13:41:37.410+00:00 but the current time is 2020-02-23 19:22 (IST). Even if the database in the local also it is inserting the same time.

Please help me with this

Comment: The database converts the datetime to UTC... If you parse your example `String` to an `OffsetDateTime` and then convert that to a `ZonedDateTime` at `"Asia/Kolkata"`, you get this: `2020-04-23T19:11:37.410+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]`. Well, not exactly 19:22, but pretty near... If you need conversion of offsets or zones, **use `java.time`**.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB stores times in UTC by default, and will convert any local time representations into this form.

1. Below is my system current time

   - print(new Date() );

     - Thu Apr 23 2020 19:29:51 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
2. But when I save this in a collection, it will be saved as UTC (ISO date), though it printed new Date in step 1 as IST

   ```
     db.getCollection("Demo").insert({dat:new Date()})

     db.getCollection("Demo").find({})
   ```

   - { "_id" : ObjectId("5ea1a0d53cd3ffdd3bef987c"), "dat" : ISODate("2020-04-23T14:06:12.564Z") }

Answer (score 0):

First, that's 5.5 hours (not 6.5 hours). And, `+00:00` means it is being stored in UTC (not in your local time). The IST offset is 
UTC+05:30.